# Trouble initializing shaders before resize on wxGLCanvas

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets

wxGLCanvas seems to hate OpenGL shaders, by not providing an initialization callback function like the one in Qt;  Making me unable to create the shaders even after creating the context myself in the constructor, like so:

`m_context = new wxGLContext(this);`

Also tried:

`SetCurrent(*m_current);`

Still no luck and GLEW keeps throwing "Missing GL Version" which indicates that the context has not been created (from Google).

I have tried:

1. Using WX_EVT() for show and activate events, still no luck.
2. Initializing shaders in the resize event, still no luck.

Is there any way to make wxGLCanvas call my initialization function before anything else?

Comment: I usually do my initialization in the paint event handler. I use a boolean member variable to indicate whether initialization has happened or not.

Comment: @KristianDuske I did that before but after using a resize event, it wouldn't work anymore because the resize event gets called first.

Comment: Why do you need to initialize OpenGL before the resize event? Doing it in the paint handler works quite well for me, and I'm also using GLEW. Here's some code, maybe it will help: https://github.com/kduske/TrenchBroom/blob/NewArchitecture/src/View/MapView.cpp

Comment: Because in the resize event I need to set the projection matrix according to the new window size.

Comment: I just save the new viewport size in the resize handler and update the matrix in the paint handler, too. I think the GLCanvas will repaint itself automatically after a resize if you call event.Skip() in the resize handler. Otherwise you can call Redraw() in the resize handler yourself. As a rule, I issue all OpenGL calls in exclusively in the paint handler, I have had strange issues on some platforms if I tried to use OpenGL outside of the paint handler.

Comment: Hmm, I think that's the only solution so I've done it.  Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific method to initialize OpenGL that gets called before everything else, but after the window was shown, in wxWidgets. You can roll your own with a member variable that indicates whether OpenGL has been initialized, and doing your initialization in the Paint event handler if the variable is false.

In my experience it is safest to issue all OpenGL commands only in the Paint event handler, so in your Size event handler, you should save the new viewport size and update the projection matrix in your Paint handler (or just query the viewport size using wxGLCanvas' GetClientRect() method).

Answer (score 0):

In the examples in http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxGLCanvas it is suggested that you do the initialization on the paint event (EVT_PAINT(BasicGLPane::render)), as said by  Kristian Duske in the comments above.

Instead you can initialize OpenGL in any other place, you just have to show the wxwidget window or frame first (e.g. frame->Show() ).

I do this:

- initialize wxGLCanvas (in my case with a wxFrame frame as parent)

  `canvas = new Canvas( (wxFrame*) frame, args);`
- show window

  `frame->Show()`

Now call your custom OpenGL initialization method in the canvas class (only once):

- set context

  `wxGLCanvas::SetCurrent(*m_context);`
- initialize glew:

  `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;`

  `GLenum err = glewInit();`

After this I compile the shaders etc.
In the paint event then only do the drawing: `glDrawArrays()` and `SwapBuffers()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, this question is pretty old and I am no longer in need for an answer, so I hope this helps someone else!